# How to improve the performance while operating with files in C

Tags: c, machine-learning, data-mining

I have implemented Naive Bayes algorithm on a large data set of 410k rows.Now all my records are getting classified correctly but the thing is the program is taking almost an hr to write the records into the corresponding files.What is the best way to improve performance of my code.Here is the below code.This piece of code is writing the 410k records into the corresponding files.Thank you.

```
    fp=fopen("sales_ok_fraud.txt","r");
        while(fgets(line,80,fp)!=NULL) //Reading each line from file to calculate the file size.
        {
                token = strtok(line,",");
                token = strtok(NULL,",");
                token = strtok(NULL,",");
                token = strtok(NULL,",");
                token = strtok(NULL,",");
                token = strtok(NULL,",");
                token1 = strtok(token,"\n");
                memcpy(mystr,&token1[0],strlen(token1)-1);
                mystr[strlen(token1)-1] = '\0';

        if( strcmp(mystr,"ok") == 0 )
            counter_ok++;
        else 
        counter_fraud++;       
    }
    printf("The no. of records with OK label are %f\n",counter_ok);
    printf("The no. of records with FRAUD label are %f\n",counter_fraud);

    prblty_ok = counter_ok/(counter_ok+counter_fraud);
    prblty_fraud = counter_fraud/(counter_ok+counter_fraud);
    printf("The probability of OK records is %f\n",prblty_ok);
    printf("The probability of FRAUD records is %f\n",prblty_fraud);
    fclose(fp);

    fp=fopen("sales_unknwn.txt","r");
    fp2=fopen("sales_unknown_ok_classified.txt","a");
    fp3=fopen("sales_unknown_fraud_classified.txt","a");
    while(fgets(line1,80,fp)!=NULL) //Reading each line from file to calculate the file size.
        {
                unknwn_attr1 = strtok(line1,",");
                unknwn_attr2 = strtok(NULL,",");
                unknwn_attr3 = strtok(NULL,",");
                unknwn_attr4 = strtok(NULL,",");
                unknwn_attr5 = strtok(NULL,",");

        //printf("%s-%s-%s-%s-%s\n",unknwn_attr1,unknwn_attr2,unknwn_attr3,unknwn_attr4,unknwn_attr5);

        fp1=fopen("sales_ok_fraud.txt","r");
        while(fgets(line,80,fp1)!=NULL) //Reading each line from file to calculate the file size.
            {
            ok_fraud_attr1 = strtok(line,",");
                    ok_fraud_attr2 = strtok(NULL,",");
                    ok_fraud_attr3 = strtok(NULL,",");
                    ok_fraud_attr4 = strtok(NULL,",");
                    ok_fraud_attr5 = strtok(NULL,",");
            ok_fraud_attr6 = strtok(NULL,",");
                    memcpy(ok_fraud_attr6_str,&ok_fraud_attr6[0],strlen(ok_fraud_attr6)-2);
                    ok_fraud_attr6_str[strlen(ok_fraud_attr6)-2] = '\0';
            //ok_fraud_attr6[strlen(ok_fraud_attr6)-2] = '\0';      
            //printf("Testing ok_fraud_attr6 - %s-%d\n",ok_fraud_attr6_str,strlen(ok_fraud_attr6_str)); 
            if( strcmp(ok_fraud_attr6_str,"ok") == 0 )
            {
                if( strcmp(unknwn_attr2,ok_fraud_attr2) == 0 )
                counter_ok_attr2++;

                if( strcmp(unknwn_attr3,ok_fraud_attr3) == 0 )
                counter_ok_attr3++;

                if( strcmp(unknwn_attr4,ok_fraud_attr4) == 0 )
                counter_ok_attr4++;

                if( strcmp(unknwn_attr5,ok_fraud_attr5) == 0 )
                counter_ok_attr5++;
            }

                    if( strcmp(ok_fraud_attr6_str,"fraud") == 0 )
                        {
                if( strcmp(unknwn_attr2,ok_fraud_attr2) == 0 )
                counter_fraud_attr2++;

                if( strcmp(unknwn_attr3,ok_fraud_attr3) == 0 )
                counter_fraud_attr3++;

                if( strcmp(unknwn_attr4,ok_fraud_attr4) == 0 )
                counter_fraud_attr4++;

                if( strcmp(unknwn_attr5,ok_fraud_attr5) == 0 )
                counter_fraud_attr5++;
            }
        }
        fclose(fp1);
        if(counter_ok_attr2 == 0)
        prblty_attr2_given_ok = (counter_ok_attr2+arbitrary_value*prblty_ok)/(counter_ok+arbitrary_value);
        else
        prblty_attr2_given_ok = (counter_ok_attr2)/(counter_ok);

        if(counter_ok_attr3 == 0)
        prblty_attr3_given_ok = (counter_ok_attr3+arbitrary_value*prblty_ok)/(counter_ok+arbitrary_value);
        else
                prblty_attr3_given_ok = (counter_ok_attr3)/(counter_ok);

        if(counter_ok_attr4 == 0)
        prblty_attr4_given_ok = (counter_ok_attr4+arbitrary_value*prblty_ok)/(counter_ok+arbitrary_value);
        else
                prblty_attr4_given_ok = (counter_ok_attr4)/(counter_ok);

        if(counter_ok_attr5 == 0)
        prblty_attr5_given_ok = (counter_ok_attr5+arbitrary_value*prblty_ok)/(counter_ok+arbitrary_value);
        else
                prblty_attr5_given_ok = (counter_ok_attr5)/(counter_ok);

        if(counter_fraud_attr2 == 0)
        prblty_attr2_given_fraud = (counter_fraud_attr2+arbitrary_value*prblty_fraud)/(counter_fraud+arbitrary_value);
        else
                prblty_attr2_given_fraud = (counter_fraud_attr2)/(counter_fraud);

        if(counter_fraud_attr3 == 0)
        prblty_attr3_given_fraud = (counter_fraud_attr3+arbitrary_value*prblty_fraud)/(counter_fraud+arbitrary_value);
        else
                prblty_attr3_given_fraud = (counter_fraud_attr3)/(counter_fraud);

        if(counter_fraud_attr4 == 0)
        prblty_attr4_given_fraud = (counter_fraud_attr4+arbitrary_value*prblty_fraud)/(counter_fraud+arbitrary_value);
        else
                prblty_attr4_given_fraud = (counter_fraud_attr4)/(counter_fraud);

        if(counter_fraud_attr5 == 0)
        prblty_attr5_given_fraud = (counter_fraud_attr5+arbitrary_value*prblty_fraud)/(counter_fraud+arbitrary_value);
        else
                prblty_attr5_given_fraud = (counter_fraud_attr5)/(counter_fraud);

        total_prblty_ok = prblty_ok*prblty_attr2_given_ok*prblty_attr3_given_ok*prblty_attr4_given_ok*prblty_attr5_given_ok;
        total_prblty_fraud = prblty_fraud*prblty_attr2_given_fraud*prblty_attr3_given_fraud*prblty_attr4_given_fraud*prblty_attr5_given_fraud;


//      printf("Testing counts for OK - %f - %f - %f - %f\n",counter_ok_attr2,counter_ok_attr3,counter_ok_attr4,counter_ok_attr5);
//      printf("Testing counts for FRAUD - %f - %f - %f - %f\n",counter_fraud_attr2,counter_fraud_attr3,counter_fraud_attr4,counter_fraud_attr5);
//      printf("Testing attribute probabilities for OK - %f - %f - %f - %f\n",prblty_attr2_given_ok,prblty_attr3_given_ok,prblty_attr4_given_ok,prblty_attr5_given_ok);
//      printf("Testing attribute probabilities for FRAUD- %f - %f - %f - %f\n",prblty_attr2_given_fraud,prblty_attr3_given_fraud,prblty_attr4_given_fraud,prblty_attr5_given_fraud);
//      printf("The final probabilities are %f - %f\n",total_prblty_ok,total_prblty_fraud);

        if(total_prblty_ok > total_prblty_fraud)
        {
            fprintf(fp2,"%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,ok\n",unknwn_attr1,unknwn_attr2,unknwn_attr3,unknwn_attr4,unknwn_attr5);
        }   
        else
        {
            fprintf(fp3,"%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,fraud\n",unknwn_attr1,unknwn_attr2,unknwn_attr3,unknwn_attr4,unknwn_attr5);
        }
        counter_ok_attr2=counter_ok_attr3=counter_ok_attr4=counter_ok_attr5=0;
        counter_fraud_attr2=counter_fraud_attr3=counter_fraud_attr4=counter_fraud_attr5=0;
    }

    fclose(fp);
        fclose(fp2);    
        fclose(fp3);
```

Comment: posting your code could potentially help

Comment: Well, this doesn't help at all. Let me give some general advice though: try not to open/close/reopen/close/reopen ... files, try to parallelize your tasks where possible, don't open your file for rw if you just need to write, try playing around with buffer sizes (if you have any)

Comment: I added the complete code.Hope it helps you guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a several things I can see right away you can do, in the order I would try them:

1. Stop with the repeated  open-write-close, open-write-close ideology on your output files. Their names are fixed and limited. Open them **all** appropriately at the start of this thing, then flush-and-close when you're done.
2. There are several logic-constructs that can be **significantly** simplified.
3. Your `strlen()` rampage needs to *significantly* be reduced. Most decent optimizing compilers will detect the unchanged source and optimize out the subsequent calls on a known-unchanged char-ptr, so I would do this last (but honestly I'd still do it as its a bad practice to call repeated `strlen()` invokes on the same data.
4. **ADDED AFTER CONVERSING WITH OP** :You repeatedly re-parse the same data file (sales_ok_fraud.txt) over and over, once for line of data in sales_unknwn.txt. 12gB/abg-line-length is a LOT of unneeded repetitious parsing if sales_ok_fraud.txt can fit in memory. Load that data *once* calculate its base stats *once*, and use the data and stats therein for the rest of your data crunch.

---

**Logic Reductions**

You can cut out a *ton* of work in one place in particular, changing this:

```
    if(strcmp(unknwn_attr2,ok_fraud_attr2) == 0 && strcmp(ok_fraud_attr6_str,"ok") == 0)
        counter_ok_attr2++;

    if(strcmp(unknwn_attr3,ok_fraud_attr3) == 0 && strcmp(ok_fraud_attr6_str,"ok") == 0)
        counter_ok_attr3++;

    if(strcmp(unknwn_attr4,ok_fraud_attr4) == 0 && strcmp(ok_fraud_attr6_str,"ok") == 0)
        counter_ok_attr4++;

    if(strcmp(unknwn_attr5,ok_fraud_attr5) == 0 && strcmp(ok_fraud_attr6_str,"ok") == 0)
        counter_ok_attr5++;

    if(strcmp(unknwn_attr2,ok_fraud_attr2) == 0 && strcmp(ok_fraud_attr6_str,"fraud") == 0)
        counter_fraud_attr2++;

    if(strcmp(unknwn_attr3,ok_fraud_attr3) == 0 && strcmp(ok_fraud_attr6_str,"fraud") == 0)
        counter_fraud_attr3++;

    if(strcmp(unknwn_attr4,ok_fraud_attr4) == 0 && strcmp(ok_fraud_attr6_str,"fraud") == 0)
        counter_fraud_attr4++;

    if(strcmp(unknwn_attr5,ok_fraud_attr5) == 0 && strcmp(ok_fraud_attr6_str,"fraud") == 0)
        counter_fraud_attr5++;
```

To this:

```
    if (strcmp(ok_fraud_attr6_str, "ok") == 0)
    {
        if(strcmp(unknwn_attr2,ok_fraud_attr2) == 0)
            counter_ok_attr2++;

        if(strcmp(unknwn_attr3,ok_fraud_attr3) == 0 )
            counter_ok_attr3++;

        if(strcmp(unknwn_attr4,ok_fraud_attr4) == 0)
            counter_ok_attr4++;

        if(strcmp(unknwn_attr5,ok_fraud_attr5) == 0)
            counter_ok_attr5++;
    }
    else if (strcmp(ok_fraud_attr6_str,"fraud") == 0)
    {
        if(strcmp(unknwn_attr2,ok_fraud_attr2) == 0)
            counter_fraud_attr2++;

        if(strcmp(unknwn_attr3,ok_fraud_attr3) == 0)
            counter_fraud_attr3++;

        if(strcmp(unknwn_attr4,ok_fraud_attr4) == 0)
            counter_fraud_attr4++;

        if(strcmp(unknwn_attr5,ok_fraud_attr5) == 0)
            counter_fraud_attr5++;
    }
```

---

**Front-Loading `sales_ok_fraud.txt`**

The following relies on the sanctity of the data format of your `sales_ok_fraud.txt` stats file, while trying to be as pedantic as possible in validating said format. It allocates a chunk of memory large enough to hold the entire file plus-one-char to treat the entire body as a single null-term-string. That buffer is then pieced-up via the same general algorithm you had prior. The result will be a table of pointers to fixed-length char-pointer arrays that can then be used iteratively in the same place you currently (and repeatedly) open, parse, use, and throw away all that content.

```
// declare an array of six string pointers
typedef char *OFAttribs[6];

// loads a table consisting of the following format:
//
// str1,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6\n
// str1,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6\n
// ...
// str1,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6
//
// any deviation from the above will cause premature termination of the loop
//  but will return whatever was able to be parsed up to the point of failure.
//  the caller should therefore always `free()` the resulting table and data
//  pointers.

size_t init_ok_fraud_data(const char *fname, OFAttribs **ppTable, char **ppTableData)
{
    if (!fname || !*fname)
        return 0;

    // check file open for thumbs up
    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "rb");
    if (!fp)
        return 0;

    // allocate enough memory to hold the entire file, plus a terminator
    fseek(fp, 0,  SEEK_END);
    long len = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0,  SEEK_SET);

    // allocate enough ram for the entire file plus terminator
    OFAttribs *pTable = NULL;
    size_t nTableLen = 0;
    char *pTableData =  malloc((len+1) * sizeof(char));
    if (NULL != pTableData)
    {
        fread(pTableData , len, 1, fp);
        pTableData[len] = 0;
    }

    // no longer need the file
    fclose(fp);

    // prime first token
    char *token = strtok(pTableData, ",");
    while (token)
    {
        // read next line of tokens
        OFAttribs attribs = { NULL };
        for (int i=0;i<4 && token; ++i)
        {
            attribs[i] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }

        // filled 0..3, set lat token and move on
        if (attribs[3] && token)
        {
            // next-to-last entry set
            attribs[4] = token;

            // line enter is only terminated by newline
            token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
            if (token)
            {
                // proper format. 6 parms, 5 commas, one new-line.
                attribs[5] = token;
                size_t slen = strlen(token);
                if (slen > 0)
                {
                    while (isspace(token[--slen]))
                        token[slen] = 0;
                }

                // make space on the master list for another.
                OFAttribs *tmp = realloc(pTable, sizeof(*tmp) * (nTableLen+1));
                if (NULL != tmp)
                {
                    pTable = tmp;
                    memcpy(pTable + nTableLen++, attribs, sizeof(attribs));
                }
                else
                {   // allocation failure.
                    printf("Error allocating memory for expanding OKFraud data set");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }
            else
            {   // not good.
                printf("Invalid line format detected. Expected ok/fraud\\n");
                break;
            }

            // next token of new line
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
    }

    // set output variables
    *ppTable = pTable;
    *ppTableData = pTableData;
    return nTableLen;
}
```

---

**Putting It Together**

Incorporating everything above has the following effect on your code base:

```
// load the ok_fraud table ONCE.
OFAttribs *okfr = NULL;
char *okfr_data = NULL;
size_t okfr_len = init_ok_fraud_data("sales_ok_fraud.txt", &okfr, &okfr_data);

// walk table to determine probabilities of ok and fraud states.
//  note: this really should be done as part of the loader.
for (size_t i=0;i<okfr_len; ++i)
{
    if (0 == strcmp("ok", okfr[i][5]))
        ++counter_ok;
    else
        ++counter_fraud;
}

printf("The no. of records with OK label are %f\n",counter_ok);
printf("The no. of records with FRAUD label are %f\n",counter_fraud);

// compute probabilites for ok and fraud states
prblty_ok = (float)counter_ok/(float)(okfr_len);
prblty_fraud = (float)counter_fraud/(float)(okfr_len);
printf("The probability of OK records is %f\n",prblty_ok);
printf("The probability of FRAUD records is %f\n",prblty_fraud);

fp=fopen("sales_unknwn.txt","r");
fp2=fopen("sales_unknown_ok_classified.txt","w");
fp3=fopen("sales_unknown_fraud_classified.txt","w");
while(fgets(line1,sizeof(line1),fp)!=NULL) //Reading each line from file to calculate the file size.
{
    char *unknwn_attr1 = strtok(line1,",");
    char *unknwn_attr2 = strtok(NULL,",");
    char *unknwn_attr3 = strtok(NULL,",");
    char *unknwn_attr4 = strtok(NULL,",");
    char *unknwn_attr5 = strtok(NULL,",");

    //printf("%s-%s-%s-%s-%s\n",unknwn_attr1,unknwn_attr2,unknwn_attr3,unknwn_attr4,unknwn_attr5);

    for (size_t i=0;i<okfr_len; ++i)
    {

        if( strcmp(okfr[i][5], "ok") == 0 )
        {
            // ok case
            if( strcmp(unknwn_attr2, okfr[i][1]) == 0 )
                counter_ok_attr2++;

            if( strcmp(unknwn_attr3, okfr[i][2]) == 0 )
                counter_ok_attr3++;

            if( strcmp(unknwn_attr4, okfr[i][3]) == 0 )
                counter_ok_attr4++;

            if( strcmp(unknwn_attr5, okfr[i][4]) == 0 )
                counter_ok_attr5++;
        }

        else // fraud case
        {
            if( strcmp(unknwn_attr2, okfr[i][1]) == 0 )
                counter_fraud_attr2++;

            if( strcmp(unknwn_attr3, okfr[i][2]) == 0 )
                counter_fraud_attr3++;

            if( strcmp(unknwn_attr4, okfr[i][3]) == 0 )
                counter_fraud_attr4++;

            if( strcmp(unknwn_attr5, okfr[i][4]) == 0 )
                counter_fraud_attr5++;
        }
    }

    if(counter_ok_attr2 == 0)
        prblty_attr2_given_ok = (counter_ok_attr2+arbitrary_value*prblty_ok)/(counter_ok+arbitrary_value);
    else
        prblty_attr2_given_ok = (counter_ok_attr2)/(counter_ok);

    if(counter_ok_attr3 == 0)
        prblty_attr3_given_ok = (counter_ok_attr3+arbitrary_value*prblty_ok)/(counter_ok+arbitrary_value);
    else
        prblty_attr3_given_ok = (counter_ok_attr3)/(counter_ok);

    if(counter_ok_attr4 == 0)
        prblty_attr4_given_ok = (counter_ok_attr4+arbitrary_value*prblty_ok)/(counter_ok+arbitrary_value);
    else
        prblty_attr4_given_ok = (counter_ok_attr4)/(counter_ok);

    if (counter_ok_attr5 == 0)
        prblty_attr5_given_ok = (counter_ok_attr5+arbitrary_value*prblty_ok)/(counter_ok+arbitrary_value);
    else
        prblty_attr5_given_ok = (counter_ok_attr5)/(counter_ok);

    if(counter_fraud_attr2 == 0)
        prblty_attr2_given_fraud = (counter_fraud_attr2+arbitrary_value*prblty_fraud)/(counter_fraud+arbitrary_value);
    else
        prblty_attr2_given_fraud = (counter_fraud_attr2)/(counter_fraud);

    if(counter_fraud_attr3 == 0)
        prblty_attr3_given_fraud = (counter_fraud_attr3+arbitrary_value*prblty_fraud)/(counter_fraud+arbitrary_value);
    else
        prblty_attr3_given_fraud = (counter_fraud_attr3)/(counter_fraud);

    if(counter_fraud_attr4 == 0)
        prblty_attr4_given_fraud = (counter_fraud_attr4+arbitrary_value*prblty_fraud)/(counter_fraud+arbitrary_value);
    else
        prblty_attr4_given_fraud = (counter_fraud_attr4)/(counter_fraud);

    if(counter_fraud_attr5 == 0)
        prblty_attr5_given_fraud = (counter_fraud_attr5+arbitrary_value*prblty_fraud)/(counter_fraud+arbitrary_value);
    else
        prblty_attr5_given_fraud = (counter_fraud_attr5)/(counter_fraud);

    total_prblty_ok = prblty_ok*prblty_attr2_given_ok*prblty_attr3_given_ok*prblty_attr4_given_ok*prblty_attr5_given_ok;
    total_prblty_fraud = prblty_fraud*prblty_attr2_given_fraud*prblty_attr3_given_fraud*prblty_attr4_given_fraud*prblty_attr5_given_fraud;


    //      printf("Testing counts for OK - %f - %f - %f - %f\n",counter_ok_attr2,counter_ok_attr3,counter_ok_attr4,counter_ok_attr5);
    //      printf("Testing counts for FRAUD - %f - %f - %f - %f\n",counter_fraud_attr2,counter_fraud_attr3,counter_fraud_attr4,counter_fraud_attr5);
    //      printf("Testing attribute probabilities for OK - %f - %f - %f - %f\n",prblty_attr2_given_ok,prblty_attr3_given_ok,prblty_attr4_given_ok,prblty_attr5_given_ok);
    //      printf("Testing attribute probabilities for FRAUD- %f - %f - %f - %f\n",prblty_attr2_given_fraud,prblty_attr3_given_fraud,prblty_attr4_given_fraud,prblty_attr5_given_fraud);
    //      printf("The final probabilities are %f - %f\n",total_prblty_ok,total_prblty_fraud);

    if(total_prblty_ok > total_prblty_fraud)
    {
        fprintf(fp2,"%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,ok\n",unknwn_attr1,unknwn_attr2,unknwn_attr3,unknwn_attr4,unknwn_attr5);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(fp3,"%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,fraud\n",unknwn_attr1,unknwn_attr2,unknwn_attr3,unknwn_attr4,unknwn_attr5);
    }
    counter_ok_attr2=counter_ok_attr3=counter_ok_attr4=counter_ok_attr5=0;
    counter_fraud_attr2=counter_fraud_attr3=counter_fraud_attr4=counter_fraud_attr5=0;
}

// free the table data and dynamic pointer array
free(okfr);
free(okfr_data);

fclose(fp);
fclose(fp2);
fclose(fp3);
return 0;
```

---

These are just a few ideas. There are more things in there to-be-sure, but these should help *enormously* in processing your file single-forward-scan with continuous output, which is about as efficient as you're going to get under these circumstances. Without question the combination of the big three: single file open+close, logic reductions and single-parse-cache'ing the sales_ok_fraud.txt file will have a huge improvement in performance, especially the first and last of these.

**EDIT** Assisted the OP in updating this processor to front-load the sales_ok_fraud.txt file content, thereby eliminating repeated loading, parsing, and promptly throwing out some 15000+ line of text to be parsed repeatedly (once per main-source input line). Answer above updated accordingly.

Comment: Hi I implemented the first two steps as you said.But still my program is running around 50 min to write the o/p.What is the best option for me to tune the code?

Comment: @SOaddict Updated to throw out yet-more-strcmps.

Comment: @If you don't get a *substantial* improvement after applying all of these, append your updated routines to your original question (do NOT delete the original code) so others can see what progress has already been done.

Comment: Hi I made all the required changes but still I dont see any improvement.Now my program executes in 50 min instead of 1 hr.What is the best possible way to handle this large data.My output is coming correct but only concern is time now.

Comment: @SOaddict Update the question with the updated code added at the end of current question. rom what you've said there has been literally *no* improvement whatsoever since updating anything at all. I find that near-impossible to understand. Please show what updates you've made. appending the updated code *to your original post; NOT in a comment.*

Comment: @SOaddict you're missing the `else` clause before the if-check for "fraud". Other than that this looks much better than what you started with.

Comment: @SOaddict How large is the "sales_ok_fraud.txt" file? I believe the 410K line-file is the "sales_unknown.txt" file, but how large is the "sales_ok_fraud.txt" file?

Comment: The size of sales_ok_fraud.txt is 511036 bytes and size of sales_unknwn.txt is 12941614 bytes.

Comment: @SOaddict Then you should be able to *substantially* increase performance by preloading the sales_ok_fraud.txt file **once** into a sequential array (or better still, a hash-mapping system) *before* you begin your main processing of sales_unkwn.txt. Half a megabyte is *nothing* for modern systems. At a minimum, preload it into a sequential array. Reloading and reparsing the same data over and over again is a killer. In that way only the counters need to be reset between process lines from unkwn.

Comment: @SOaddict give it a shot. I'm installing a hardwood floor and am otherwise detained, but I'll check back later this evening (PST) and see how you did.

Answer (score 1):

@m02ph3u5 is right. Keep your files open, take the calls to fopen and fclose out of the loops.

```
inputFile = fopen("sales_unknwn.txt","r");
okayFile = fopen("sales_ok_fraud.txt","r");
unknownOkayFile = fopen("sales_unknown_ok_classified.txt","a");
unknownFraudFile = fopen("sales_unknown_fraud_classified.txt","a");

// your loops go here

fclose(inputFile);
fclose(okayFile);
fclose(unknownOkayFile);
fclose(unknownFraudFile);
```

If it's still slow, run a sampling profiler on your app with a subset of the test data as input just to keep the turnaround fast. This will tell you where the program is spending it's time. You might be surprised. If you don't know have a profiler to use, you can do a poor man's simulation of a sampling profiler by running your app with a debugger, breaking into the debugger repeatedly and noting which function it is running in. If you see it in a certain function or on a certain line most of the time, that's probably a hotspot that you can optimize.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

•  Repeatedly opening files for append, closing them, and reopening them is very expensive.  This is because I/O is much slower than in-memory access, and you're forcing the disk to open each file and seek to the end *every time you write to it.*  Better to open them once at the beginning and close them at the end, unless you're concerned the program will crash and you'll lose the data you've written so far.

•  You can replace the lines

```
memcpy(ok_fraud_attr6_str, &ok_fraud_attr6[0], strlen(ok_fraud_attr6)-2);
ok_fraud_attr6_str[strlen(ok_fraud_attr6)-2] = '\0';
```

with

```
ok_fraud_attr6[strlen(ok_fraud_attr6)-2] = '\0';
```

and then use `ok_fraud_attr6` in your tests.  Since `strtok` is destructive (a quick search will be worth your time to learn why it's often a bad idea to use it at all), you needn't worry about preserving the contents of `line` or `ok_fraud_attr6`.

•  When you find yourself writing the same code over and over again, it's often a clue that your algorithm is inefficient.  Instead of

```
if ((some_unique_test) && (a_common_test))
  do_some_stuff;
if ((some_other_unique_test) && (a_common_test))
  do_other_stuff;
```

you can write

```
if (a_common_test) {
  if (some_unique_test)
    do_some_stuff;
  if (some_other_unique_test)
    do_other_stuff;
}
```

Note, however, that only the first suggestion is likely to have a noticeable effect on the program's execution time, though they're all good habits to learn.

Jason's recommendation to use a profiler is very good advice and can't be emphasized enough.  Programmers--even experienced ones--are notoriously awful at predicting where the bottlenecks in their code are.  Next to a debugger, a profile is your best friend.