# Storing a data file into a double dimension array using C

Tags: c, arrays, string, file

I am trying to store a string data file into a multi-dimensional array using C.My sample data looks as below.I am thinking to use below char declaration for storing my data.Please kindly advise me if there is any other method.

```
char *array[6][10];

53,v42,p11,51097,310780,ok
56,v45,p11,260,1925,ok
68,v42,p11,51282,278770,ok
77,v50,p11,46903,281485,ok
82,v46,p12,475,2600,ok
84,v48,p12,433,3395,ok
96,v49,p14,212,1545,ok
163,v50,p20,373819,1006375,ok
204,v50,p26,36917,117195,ok
241,v70,p33,21777,91360,ok
```

Comment: Is this your sales_ok_fraud.txt file, SO? If so, I would declare it as a struct containing a line buffer and a set of char-offsets fixed up using strtok. Assuming it is related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436307/how-to-improve-the-performance-while-operating-with-files-in-c). There are ways to do it even more efficient than that, honestly. esp if the data is known-good and the size is limited as you said (500K or so as I recall).

Comment: Yea it's related to the same ques...

Comment: I am not comfortable at using structure so I am thinking to use a char *arr[i][j].

Comment: That will totally work. Is this sample above exemplary of the content of your ok/fraud file ?

Comment: Yea the above one is my sample file.But just the no. of rows is different.

Comment: Any chance you can upload the full file to a downloadable link somewhere?

Comment: @WhozCraig Can I email you the code otherwise?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19737/discussion-between-whozcraig-and-soaddict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this sample program will help you to address your issue. I used structure and sscanf. This is the nice way to address this issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct data
{
    char date[100];
    char state[100];
    char profit[100];
    char revenue[100];
};

int main()
{
      char line[4096] = {'\0'};
      char t1[100], t2[100], t3[100], t4[100];
      struct data d[2];
      int i = 0;
      while(fgets(line, 4096, stdin) != NULL) {
              sscanf(line, "%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%s", &t1, &t2, &t3, &t4);
              strcpy(d[i].date, t1);
              strcpy(d[i].state, t2);
              strcpy(d[i].profit, t3);
             strcpy(d[i++].revenue, t4);
     }
     i = 0;
     while(i<2){
             printf("%s %s %s %s\n", d[i].date, d[i].state, d[i].profit, d[i].revenue);
             i++;
     }
 }
```

$> a./exe < file

$> cat file

```
12/2/2012,TN,1200,14000
12/3/2012,KA,2333554,424
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine, if you want it to be strings.

What I suggest is to not allocate a string for every single field.  Instead, read a line from the file, allocate a single string for it, tokenise out the commas, and store the pointers in your 2D array.

Or indeed, if your data file fits easily into memory, there's no reason not to read the entire thing and tokenise.  Effectively, you just use your array as an index into the buffer.

Comment: I already applied strtok function on the data and extracted the tokens.

Comment: I concur. this file is only about 0.5 MB. I would slam the entire thing into memory, null-terminate it, an build a dynamic array of `char *ptr[6]` lists, each of which is fed a pointer in data image as it is processed and terminated with strtok.

Answer (score 1):

There are many other ways to do it; some will depend on whether you've learned about structures yet.

One point to note: C uses 'row-major' ordering for arrays, so most programmers would write `char *array[10][6];` for 10 rows of 6 columns each.

You could decide that instead of using `char *`, you allow, say, 10 characters per string, and use:

```
char array[10][6][10];
```

This would fit the data shown (with a little room to spare; the second 10 could be as small as 8 for the data shown).  It would require a lot less dynamic memory management.

Alternatively, you could define a structure that represents a line:

```
struct csv_line
{
    int  col1;
    char col2[4];
    char col3[4];
    int  col4;
    int  col5;
    char col6[4];  // Correct length uncertain...
};
```

And then have a 1-dimensional array of these:

```
struct csv_line array[10];
```

This is more or less how I'd do it.  Note that the structure uses 24 bytes per line compared with 48 per line in `char array[10][6][8];`, and compared with 48 bytes for pointers plus the actual strings and storage overhead for the `char *` versions on a 64-bit machine.  The total storage for the char pointer version could easily be 144 bytes per row on a 64-bit machine.

Clearly, this analysis of size assumes that you have separate allocations for each string.  If you read each line of data into a separately allocated line and then store pointers to the parts of the line, the storage overhead is (dramatically) reduced.   A lot will depend on how you are going to use the data.  If you're going to treat the numeric-looking fields as numbers, then I'd use the structure; it will save on data conversions later.